# What do I need to do to modify my plot (ggplot2) to a gt table?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gt

Edit: Having watched the tutorial at https://rfortherestofus.com/2023/10/ggplots-in-gt-tables I think the question should have been "How can I pass more than one variable into `text_transform()`... in gt?

Here is the tutorial example where `Distribuition` contains the species name and is all that is required for the plot.

```
penguin_weights |>
  mutate(Distribution = species) |>
  gt() |>
  tab_spanner(
    label = 'Penguin\'s Weight',
    columns = -species
  ) |> 
  cols_label_with(fn = str_to_title) |> 
  fmt_number(decimals = 2) |> 
  cols_align('left', columns = species) |> 
  text_transform(
    locations = cells_body(columns = 'Distribution'), # this contains 1 value, how do I pass multiple?
    fn = function(column) {
      map(column, plot_violin_species) |>
        ggplot_image(height = px(50), aspect_ratio = 3)
    }
  )
```

---

OP:
I know it's generally frowned upon to ask multiple questions in a thread but I want to make sure I'm going down the right path with my sub-steps.

I would like to add the following ggplot to a gt table as [outlined here](https://gt.albert-rapp.de/fancy_stuff#add-arbitrary-plots-to-your-table).

[image]

This plot shows a selected player's goals per 90 rate (0.89) along with every player in the conference (purple) and all the remaining players in grey.

Here is the chicken and egg issue I'm not sure how to start on.

1. I would like to add these charts for a select number of individuals, but I need the whole dataset to create the entire chart. Does that mean I need to pass two different datasets into the function? One that will contain the individuals I would like to plot, and the other with all the individuals in the dataset?
2. This most likely will require me to change the function from entering an individual, their team, and conference - to being able to iterate over a list, depending on how that is passed from above. Which I'm not sure how to do as well.

If that doesn't make sense, hopefully this will better explain:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

# Custom function
zscore_plot <- function(df, player_name, team, conference, conference_color = "steelblue", raw_value) {
  
  # Create z_scores for the supplied stat
  df <- df |>
    mutate(z_score = scale({{raw_value}})[,1])
  
  # Find the mean, sd, min, and max for the raw scores in order to set the x-axis limits
  this_mean <- df |> pull({{raw_value}}) |> mean()
  this_sd <- df |> pull({{raw_value}}) |> sd()
  scale_max <- (4 * this_sd) + this_mean
  scale_min <- (-4 * this_sd) + this_mean
  
  # Plot the z_score
  plot <- ggplot() +
    geom_point(data = df, aes(x = z_score, y = 0), alpha = 0.25, color = "grey", size = 3) +
    geom_point(data = df |>
                 filter(conference == {{conference}}),
               aes(x = z_score, y = 0),
               alpha = 0.25,
               color = conference_color,
               size = 3
    ) +
    # geom_vline(xintercept = 0, color = "lightgrey", lwd = 0.25) +
    geom_segment(aes(x = 0, xend = 0, y = -0.05, yend = 0.05), color = "lightgrey", lwd = 0.25) +
    geom_point(data = df |>
                 filter(player == player_name,
                        team == team),
               aes(x = z_score, y = 0),
               alpha = 1,
               color = "red",
               fill = "white",
               shape = 21,
               size = 3
    ) +
    geom_label(data = df |>
                 filter(player == player_name,
                        team == team),
               aes(x = z_score,
                   y = 0,
                   label = {{raw_value}}),
               alpha = 1,
               color = "red",
               fill = "white",
               size = 3,
               nudge_y = 0.05) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
    xlim(-4, 4) +
    # ylim(0,0.5) +
    theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), 
                             "cm")) +
    ylab(element_blank()) +
    xlab(element_blank()) +
    # coord_fixed(ratio = 2)
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,0.75),
                    clip = "off")
  
  # Plot the secondary (raw value) axis
  value_axis <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = {{raw_value}}, y = 0)) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
    xlim(scale_min, scale_max) +
    theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          axis.line.x = element_line(),
          aspect.ratio = 1e-8,
          plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), 
                             "cm"))+
    ylab(element_blank()) +
    xlab(element_blank())
  
  # Combine the two plots
  plot / value_axis
}

# Data
df <- structure(list(player = c('A. Anderson', 'B. Brown', 'C. Carter', 'D. Davis', 'E. Evans', 'F. Foster',
                                'G. Garcia', 'H. Hernandez', 'I. Johnson', 'K. Kelly'),
                     team = c('Rabbits', 'Pandas', 'Dolphins', 'Rabbits', 'Gorillas', 'Buffaloes', 'Elephants',
                              'Zebras', 'Elephants', 'Armadillos'),
                     conference = c('AAC', 'ABC', 'ACC', 'AAC', 'ADC', 'AEC', 'AFC', 'AGC', 'AFC', 'AHC'), 
                     minutes_played = c(1676, 1483, 809, 1133, 1373, 583, 720, 1148, 1022, 1556), 
                     non_penalty_goals_per_90 = c(1.13, 1.03, 0.89, 0.87, 0.85, 0.77, 0.75, 0.71, 0.7, 0.69), 
                     shots_on_target_per_90 = c(3.06, 2.91, 2.34, 2.07, 1.77, 1.39, 1.5, 2.12, 1.67, 1.33), 
                     xg_per_90 = c(1.02,5.16, 3.56, 3.81, 3.02, 3.09, 3, 4.86, 3.87, 2.37), 
                     touches_in_box_per_90 = c(6.98, 7.34, 5.01, 6.43, 3.28, 3.86, 5, 7.06, 5.99, 3.3), 
                     successful_attacking_actions_per_90 = c(8.27, 7.53, 4.12, 4.61, 4.59, 2.93, 3.38, 7.45, 7.57, 7.81), 
                     offensive_duels_per_90 = c(18.04, 12.5, 10.01, 12.71, 10.16, 12.66, 9.5, 14.27, 18.85, 17.99), 
                     received_long_passes_per_90 = c(2.2, 2.67, 4.67, 1.67, 0.98, 2.93, 1.75, 3.53, 2.91, 1.91), 
                     deep_completions_per_90 = c(1.66, 1.4, 1.33, 1.59, 0.79, 0.15, 0.75, 1.41, 0.62, 0.75), 
                     key_passes_per_90 = c(0.81, 0.61, 0.22, 0.48, 0.13, 0.15, 0.25, 0.94, 0.26, 0.87), 
                     offensive_duels_won_per_90 = c(6.55, 4.61, 3.34, 3.57, 4.13, 3.24, 3.25, 5.96, 6.96, 7.75),
                     ribbles_per_90 = c(8.22, 5.7, 2.11, 3.97, 3.93, 3.09, 3.25, 8.15, 7.84, 8.16)),
                class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))

# Working example of a single plot
df |>
  zscore_plot("A. Anderson", "Rabbits", conference = "ACC", conference_color = "#4f2d7f", raw_value = non_penalty_goals_per_90)

# What I need help sorting out...
df |>
  select(player, team, conference, non_penalty_goals_per_90) |>
  # Select the top 3 players.... but I need the entire data frame to pass to the zscore_plot function... !!!!!!!!!!!
  arrange(desc(non_penalty_goals_per_90)) |>
  slice_head(n = 3) |>
  mutate(plot = player) |>
  gt() +
  # Add custom plot to cells via text_transform
  text_transform(
    locations = cells_body(columns = 'plot'),
    fn = zscore_plot()
  )
```

So to reiterate, I would like to create a gt table with the top 3 individuals for `non_penalty_goals_per_90` but need to include the entire data frame for creating the plot. In addition, I would need to modify the custom function to work row-wise on whatever individuals are in the gt table.

Comment: There are tutorials online that show approaches for this, like here: https://rfortherestofus.com/2023/10/ggplots-in-gt-tables.

Comment: That's essential the same tutorial I posted above. I guess my question is more about how do I get my function to be able to use a sub-set of individuals, while still using the full set of individuals to plot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach to make your code work which essentially follows the steps in the tutorial you referenced. Main difference to the tutorial is that your function requires inputs from three columns of your table. To this end I pass the three pieces of information as one character string separated by a `";"`.

Note: I also did some tweaks to your plotting function, i.e. I use `coord_fixed(clip = "off", ratio = 3)` instead of `coord_cartesian()` and increased the size for the label to `48 / .pt`. But I'm afraid your plotting function requires more tweaks to make all the details visible, like e.g. increasing the size of the points and the font size of the axis text.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gt)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(purrr)
library(patchwork)

df |>
  select(player, team, conference, goals = non_penalty_goals_per_90) |>
  arrange(desc(goals)) |>
  slice_head(n = 3) |>
  mutate(plot = paste(player, team, conference, sep = ";")) |>
  gt() |>
  text_transform(
    locations = cells_body(columns = "plot"),
    fn = function(column) {
      map(
        column,
        \(x) {
          x <- strsplit(x, split = ";")[[1]]
          zscore_plot(
            df, x[[1]], x[[2]], x[[3]],
            raw_value = non_penalty_goals_per_90
          )
        }
      ) |>
        ggplot_image(height = 25, aspect_ratio = 3)
    }
  )
```

[image]

**PLotting Function**

```
zscore_plot <- function(df, player_name, team, conference,
                        conference_color = "steelblue", raw_value) {
  # Create z_scores for the supplied stat
  df <- df |>
    mutate(z_score = scale({{ raw_value }})[, 1])

  # Find the mean, sd, min, and max for the raw scores in order to set the x-axis limits
  this_mean <- df |>
    pull({{ raw_value }}) |>
    mean()
  this_sd <- df |>
    pull({{ raw_value }}) |>
    sd()
  scale_max <- (4 * this_sd) + this_mean
  scale_min <- (-4 * this_sd) + this_mean

  # Plot the z_score
  plot <- ggplot() +
    geom_point(
      data = df, aes(x = z_score, y = 0), alpha = 0.25,
      color = "grey", size = 3
    ) +
    geom_point(
      data = df |>
        filter(conference == {{ conference }}),
      aes(x = z_score, y = 0),
      alpha = 0.25,
      color = conference_color,
      size = 3
    ) +
    geom_segment(aes(x = 0, xend = 0, y = -0.05, yend = 0.05),
      color = "lightgrey", lwd = 0.25
    ) +
    geom_point(
      data = df |>
        filter(
          player == player_name,
          team == team
        ),
      aes(x = z_score, y = 0),
      alpha = 1,
      color = "red",
      fill = "white",
      shape = 21,
      size = 3
    ) +
    geom_label(
      data = df |>
        filter(
          player == player_name,
          team == team
        ),
      aes(
        x = z_score,
        y = 0,
        label = {{ raw_value }}
      ),
      alpha = 1,
      color = "red",
      fill = "white",
      size = 48 / .pt,
      nudge_y = 0.05
    ) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
    xlim(-4, 4) +
    theme(
      panel.background = element_blank(),
      axis.ticks = element_blank(),
      plot.margin = margin()
    ) +
    labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
    coord_fixed(ratio = 3, clip = "off")


  # Plot the secondary (raw value) axis
  value_axis <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = {{ raw_value }}, y = 0)) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
    xlim(scale_min, scale_max) +
    theme(
      panel.background = element_blank(),
      axis.ticks = element_blank(),
      axis.line.x = element_line(),
      aspect.ratio = 1e-8,
      plot.margin = margin()
    ) +
    labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)

  # Combine the two plots
  plot / value_axis
}
```

Comment: Was there any other significant tweaks to the custom function? I tried changing it based on your suggestion and running your code, but ran into errors. I've been playing with it and will see if I can find what errors were being thrown from the original.

Comment: Hm. Basically no. I just added the code for your function with my adjustments.